# how to catch or hook any call to object in javascript

Tags: javascript, proxy-classes

I am trying to proxing an Javascript object in which I could redirect any call to this object to a specific method, this mean for example.

```
var A = {}
A.prototype.proxy = function() {
 //do...
}
b = new A();
b.myMethod(); // --> Internally will call A.proxy()?
```

then, I redirect all call to A.proxy() this is possible in JavaScript?

Comment: Yes, but then you will likely need to write proxies for all methods you want to monitor/hook.

Answer (score -1):

No, it is not. The core JS language doesn't have such a feature.

Comment: Well, after in deep research, there is and feature that Moz has implemented and is target to ECMA-6 call proxy https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy

Comment: After deep research you found and experimental future that is only supported in firefox and yet it seems you dont understand the question. As the documentation says: "Proxies are new objects; it's not possible to "proxyfy" an existing object." and the question is asking if it is possible to directly call any function on the existing object. So the strict answer to this question is no.